# How to disable debug logs in aws cloudwatch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I wanted to set log levels to info(using springboot). I restricted through application.properties

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

working fine in local as standalone application

The same application when I am converting as a aws lambda then it's not setting log levels to info and getting unwanted default debug logs. please see below log

```
10:15:35
10:15:35.140 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@77167fb7
10:15:35.140 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@77167fb7

10:15:35
10:15:35.178 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'

10:15:35
10:15:35.560 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'

10:15:35
10:15:35.563 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'

10:15:35
10:15:35.566 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'

10:15:35
10:15:35.568 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'

10:15:35
10:15:35.584 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'webConfigLambda'

10:15:35
10:15:35.591 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'getRestTemplate'

10:15:36
10:15:36.263 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean '
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.